# Need frame ticks on all sides and the y-axis to be in scientific notation

Tags: ticks, frame

I am trying to make a plot that has frame ticks on all sides and the y-axis needs to be in scientific notation. I can get it to do one or the other, but not both. Please help!

```
`ListLogPlot[nmBaseline, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, AxesOrigin -> {200, 0}, Joined -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Wavelength, [nm]", 10], 
 Style["Transmission", 15]}, FrameTicks -> All {ScientificForm}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Baseline Transmission Data", ImageSize -> Large]`
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Next time, please consider adding some fake, random data so that your code is executable. Hope you become a regular here :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like (as you did not give any data, I take some random data):

```
nmBaseline = 200 + 100 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20];
ListLogPlot[nmBaseline, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, AxesOrigin -> {200, 0}, Joined -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Wavelength, [nm]", 10], 
   Style["Transmission", 15]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Baseline Transmission Data", ImageSize -> Large
 , FrameTicks -> {Automatic, 
   Table[{y, ScientificForm[y, 2]}, {y, 120., 280, 20}]}]
```

[image]